# Adding 20 1s to a binary 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, path-finding

I'm creating a pathfinding program and I have a 2d int array as with 1s indicating obstacles you can pass through/on and 0s meaning you can.

The starting grid is as follows:

```
int[][] map = {
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        };
```

The start point of this is at [0, 0] and the end point is at [9, 9].

I want to create a method that takes map and returns it with 20 random obstacles (1s) in random positions however, the start point, end point and existing obstacles cannot be altered.

Comment: What exactly can't be altered?  Any already existing 1's?  Or just (0,0, and (9,9)?

Comment: the existing 1s, (0,0) and (9,9) cant be altered

Comment: @balse98 Is it required that there must be a path from (0,0) to (9,9) after all the obstacles have been added? Guaranteeing that a path exists makes the problem harder, especially as the number of obstacles increases.

Comment: No a path doesn't have to exist, if a path isn't possible after adding obstacles the program prints "No path found"

Answer (score 1):

You have many options on how to do it. You can prepare it like this:

```html
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         Random random = new Random();
         int[][] map = new int[10][10];//you can user your existing array
         map[0][0] = 1;
         map[9][9] = 1;
        
         int counter = 20;
         while (counter > 0){
             int x = random.nextInt(10); 
             int y = random.nextInt(10);
             if(map[x][y] != 1){
                 System.out.println(x + " " + y);
                 map[x][y]=1;
                 counter--;
             }
         }
         
        map[0][0] = 0;
        map[9][9] = 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works great! I didn't think about temporarily changing the start and end points to 1.

Comment: You're not generating and `x and y` values of `9` so your are not referencing all of the map. Change `random.nextInt(9);` to `random.nextInt(10);`  nextInt is exclusive of the value supplied.

Comment: True! The solution is updated.